# Understanding grok-pattern to configure LogStash for Advanced IIS log

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, iis-logs

I switched from normal IIS log to Advanced IIS log and have some trouble parsing a log entry correctly to my Elastic Search / Kibana Setup.

The problematic entry is the cs_cookie entry.

The entry for that value can be like this:

```
".ASPXANONYMOUS=lCoa4IyW0AEkAAAAMWQzM2Y3YTktZTE4MC00N2Q0LWFjNzEtMmQ3NzFlODk2ZDA50; DNNPersonalization=<profile><item key=""Usability:UserMode9"" type=""System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b766a5c561934e089""><string>VIEW</string></item></profile>"
```

So it contains multiple spaces and quotes. I used the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) but couldn't find a solution, please advise me.

Comment: Post your best attempt and what went wrong.

Comment: my best attempt was using GREEDYDATA, it picked up everything :)  and with everything i mean even the next log entries...so spaces and " where ignored.

Comment: So Alain, can you help me out? I am still at the same point here. I am about to remove the cookie part from IIS if I can't figure this out :)

Answer (score 1):

To build up a pattern, start from the left side and examine each piece as you move to the right.

Start with %{GREEDYDATA:remainder}, which will match everything into a field called "remainder".

Your sample string starts with a quote, so add that:

```
"%{GREEDYDATA:remainder}
```

Now remainder won't have the initial quote any more.

The next piece looks like a key/value pair that ends with a semi-colon, so add that:

```
"%{NOTSPACE:key1}=%{NOTSPACE:value1}; %{GREEDYDATA:remainder}
```

Looking at what's left in "remainder" shows, at a high level, another key/value pair.  You could split that out, or add more detailed parsing to get the pieces from inside the second value.

Since your sample is really two key/value pairs, so you might do the initial split with the kv{} filter and then grok{} those pieces as needed.